# Avoid text overflow outside a box in Latex

Tags: latex

I have a long text (of unknown size) but I only have a fixed size space to display it. To avoid the text to overflow this space, I want it to be croped in order to make it small enough to enter in it.

For example, with the following code, we see that the text is much longer than the available space (symbolized by the box). So I would like to know how to cut the text that overflows the box, in order to shorten it (shorten to *100pt* for this example).

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

    \fbox{
    \parbox[][100pt][t]{3cm}{
        The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog.
    }
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach with the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][3cm][t]{100pt},frame,clip=true,trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm}
  The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog.
\end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]